# can't make this prolog program work, prolog rules, 'or' operator, prolog arithmetics

Tags: prolog

I'm new to prolog and I'm stuck with an exercise.

I have a prolog database called "languages.pl" and I'm working on a file called "program.pl", that have the rules.

A language have a name and a year of creation, for example:

```
COBOL, 1960
PASCAL, 1971
C, 1971
```

And those languages have predecessors, like:

Scheme, Lisp ------ Lisp is the predecessor os scheme.

So, I want to find a language Lp that precedes a language L but with, at least, a decade of years between their creations, like:

```
?- ling_precedes_decade(Lp, L).
Lp = ’C++’,
L = ’Rust’ .
```

I tought of something like:

```
ling_precedes_decade(Lp, L) :-
    language(Lp, X),
    language(L, Y),
    ((X-Y) > 9); ((X-Y) < -9).
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: It really looks like you need to do a few searches for "Prolog Programming Language Arithmetic". I found this: http://www-users.york.ac.uk/~sjh1/courses/L334css/complete/complete2su8.html

Comment: *But it doesn't work*...., can you elaborate? Also, you did read the Prolog documentation, right? So you know that `or` is not a pre-defined Prolog operator?

Comment: @lurker I know that 'or' isn't a pre-defined prolog operator, i guess it would be ';', but i typed it wrong there, thanks anyway. About the "it doesn't work", I don't know what to elaborate, it does not give me an output.

Comment: @Enigmativity I didn't found something that could help me here (or didn't noticed). But I will keep searching, thank you!

Comment: Did you check the operator precedence table for Prolog? `,` has higher precedence than `;`. So your logic is equivalent to the grouping: `( anguage(Lp, X),
    language(L, Y),
    ((X-Y) > 9) ) ; ((X-Y) < -9).`

Comment: Also, can you show how you asserted your facts? You are showing, for example, `COBOL, 1960`, but it's unclear how you asserted this. If you did `language(COBOL, 1960)` that will be incorrect since `COBOL` would be seen as a variable in Prolog.

Comment: I'm sorry about how poorly made was constructed my question. My facts were asserted like this:
language('Fortran I',1957).
language('Fortran II',1958).
language('Algol 58',1958).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things to mention with respect to the question posting.

You listed example facts as:

```
COBOL, 1960
PASCAL, 1971
C, 1971
```

Since you didn't show these as actual Prolog facts, I can only speculate as to how you asserted them. The correct way, in order for `COBOL` to be an atom, is to use quotes, since in Prolog the initial capital letter would otherwise make `COBOL` a variable.

```
language('COBOL', 1960).
language('PASCAL', 1971).
language('C', 1971).
```

Then in your predicate, you are not being mindful of precedence rules for `,` versus `;`.  `;` is lower precedence than `,`. So your predicate behavior would be as if grouped as follows:

```
lang_precedes_decade(Lp, L) :-
    ( language(Lp, X),
      language(L, Y),
      ((X-Y) > 9) )
    ; ((X-Y) < -9).
```

You need to group your "or" appropriately:

```
lang_precedes_decade(Lp, L) :-
    language(Lp, X),
    language(L, Y),
    ( ((X-Y) > 9); ((X-Y) < -9) ).
```

Then if you query, you'll get this:

```
| ?- lang_precedes_decade(Lp, L).

L = 'PASCAL'
Lp = 'COBOL' ? ;

L = 'C'
Lp = 'COBOL' ? ;

L = 'COBOL'
Lp = 'PASCAL' ? ;

L = 'COBOL'
Lp = 'C' ? ;

no
```

Notice now that you get redundant results due to the symmetry of your checking against the facts. Since `language(Lp, X), language(L, Y)` will capture the symmetry already (you'll get the solutions where `Lp` and `L` are swapped), you don't need the extra check for `< -9`:

```
lang_precedes_decade(Lp, L) :-
    language(Lp, YearLp),
    language(L, YearL),
    (YearL-YearLp) > 9.    % Lp precedes L
```

This will result in:

```
| ?- lang_precedes_decade(Lp, L).

L = 'PASCAL'
Lp = 'COBOL' ? a

L = 'C'
Lp = 'COBOL'

no
| ?-
```

Comment: First I tried to do like this:
lang_precedes_decade(Lp, L) :- language(Lp, X), language(L, Y), (X-Y) > 9.

But it wouldn't work because it returned me every language with 10 years between then, instead of languages that have a connection between them (precedes).

So I tried:
lang_precedes_decade(Lp, L) :- predecessor(L, Lp), language(Lp, X), language(L, Y), (X-Y) > 9.

And this won't work either.

Comment: @Mtr if you want strictly `Lp` precedes `L` then you'd want `(Y-X) > 9`. See my updated answer. You don't need `predecessor(L, Lp)`. I've run this code and it works as I've shown.

Comment: Thank you very much! Also, now I have another question, what if I wanted to return all the languages of some decade? Does Prolog have something like that? Lets say a predicate like "language_from_decade(L, D)", if I entered a year like 1950, I could just pick the languages between 1950 and 1950+9. But what if I enter 1953? I want to transform the 53 to 50 or something like that.

Comment: @Mtr, sure Prolog has some arithmetic ability. But if you are assuming that the passed in decade looks like 1950 (a year evenly on a decade) you could simply write, `language(L, Y), Y >= D, Y =< D+9.` (Note that in Prolog `=<` is less than or equal, not `<=` since that can look like propositional logic operator.)

Comment: but what if the input is something like 1953? That wouldn't work.

Comment: @Mtr Are you wanting to find all the languages within the same decade as 1953? Just look at the [arithmetic operators that Prolog supports](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=functions). What you want is easy to do and a number of ways to do it. You could, for example, write: `same_decade(Year, Language) :- language(Language, Y), Decade is Year - (Year mod 10), Y >= Decade, Y =< Decade + 9.`

Comment: I'm really thankful! You helped me a lot. Now I understand.